# accessing public variable in form 2

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I trying to develop a windows form application. In here I want to call a variable both form 1 and form 2. I got the vale to ComputerId variable.

```
namespace ComData
{
    public partial class addnew : Form
    {
        string ConnString = "Server=localhost;Database=machinedetails;UID=root;Encrypt=true;";
        public int ComputerId { get; set; } 

        public addnew()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnnext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnString))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand())
                {
                    if (this.txtbranch.Text != "" && this.txtcostcenter.Text != "")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            MySqlParameter branchparam = new MySqlParameter("@branch", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 16);
                            MySqlParameter costcenterparam = new MySqlParameter("@costcenter", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 16);

                            comm.Connection = conn;
                            conn.Open();
                            comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO computerdetails(branch,costcenter) VALUES (@branch, @costcenter);Select last_insert_id();";
                            comm.Parameters.Add(branchparam);
                            comm.Parameters.Add(costcenterparam);
                            comm.Prepare();

                            String branch = txtbranch.Text;
                            String costcenter = txtcostcenter.Text;

                            comm.Parameters[0].Value = branch;
                            comm.Parameters[1].Value = costcenter;

                            MySqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
                            if (reader.HasRows)
                            {
                                reader.Read();
                                ComputerId = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
                                MessageBox.Show("value is" + ComputerId);
                            }



                            this.Hide();
                            newdetails nd = new newdetails();
                            nd.ShowDialog();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please fill the values");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know how to call this ComputerId variable in form 2. Please help me.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

This code-block belongs to the form2 where you open your addnew-form

```
addnew testObj = new addnew(); //init
testObj.show() //or testObj.showDialog();
int id = testObj.ComputerId; //getting the id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a parameterized constructor to `newdetails` form. And then pass the integer value there. Something like this:

```
// In newdetails form

private int computerId;

public newdetails(int compId){
computerId = compId;
}

// in addnew form
newdetails nd = new newdetails(ComputerId);
```

Answer (score 0):

In newdetails form:

```
private addNew _addNew { get; set; }

public newdetails(addNEw parent)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _addNew = parent; 
}

//you can access any public variable at addNew form with:
int test = _addNew.PublicVariableName
```

in your addnew form:

```
newetails x = new newdetails(this);
x.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to move the ComputerId variable to "Program Class" inside Program.cs file, like this:

```
public class Program
{
     public static int ComputerId;

    //Main and other methods......
}
```

Now you can access this variable from all of your forms simply like this:

```
int cid=Program.ComputerId;
```

As Simple As That.